# React Redirect to another route from redux action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, redux-saga

I am using Redux for state management and saga as middleware. The application works fine. I have a component that have a few search fields. Below is simplified version of the form:

```
 <div>
    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} noValidate>
      <div>
        <div >
          <label> ORIGIN City </label>
          <br/>

          <select name="originCity" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {this.props.airportData.map(airport => (
              <option key={airport.key} value={airport.key}> {airport.name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>

        <div c>
          <label> DESTINATION City </label>
          <br/>
          <select name="destinationCity" 
                  onChange={this.handleChange}>
            {this.props.airportData.map(airport => (
              <option key={airport.key} value={airport.key}> {airport.name}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
```

On Submit I am calling an Action (which in turn calls the api) which will search flights between Origin and destination. The requirement is if the api returns no data, I need to stay on the same component an display an error message but if the api returns result, I need to navigate to another route. I know I can navigate to another route from an action but how do I display the data returned from the api without calling the api twice?

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated?

Comment: Welcome to Stackowerflow! The returned data should be in your store so you can reach it after the navigation with a selector.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I also need to make this work if the user just types in the url (route) in browser with query params. For example http://someurl/searchResults?originCity=xyz&destinationCity=abc. I would not know if the user is coming to this url because someone send them the url in an email or they are routed to this component from search component.

Comment: For query params, look into using "ownParams" and how react-router allows you to define routes such as "/searchResults/:originCity/:destinationCity.